# Where is the jar file for com.ibm.portal.auth.tai.HTTPBasicAuthTAI

Tags: java, websphere

Where is the jar for WebSphere Global security > Trust association > Interceptors > com.ibm.portal.auth.tai.HTTPBasicAuthTAI?

Answer (score 0):

It is located here: ..\AppServer\lib\ext\wp.auth.tai.jar